# Simple javascript string extraction

Tags: javascript, regex

I have such string:

```
"{{foo}} is {{bar}}"
```

I would like to extract values from {{}}, how I can achieve this?
Expected result is

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

I tried

```
"{{foo}} is {{bar}}".match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g)
```

But its not working as I expected.

Comment: Is this some kind of templating? Are you going to replace them with something?

Comment: @georg its from templating, and I am doing very simple prototype where I just need to extract all variables from templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `exec` in a loop like this to grab capturing groups with global flag in JS:

```
var m;
var re = /\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g
var str = "{{foo}} is {{bar}}"
var matches = [];

while((m=re.exec(str)) != null) {
   matches.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
//=> ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: This is the best solution posted - if you're using regex, use it for the whole job.  Don't then fall back to string mangling because you're not getting the right output.

Comment: @Tresdin Not really - it's a very straightforward implementation of how to use `.exec`, and doesn't require post-manipulation of the found values.

Comment: @JamesThorpe It does require a post-manipulation. How can you get the expected array of values with just `exec`, without the loop?

Comment: @Tresdin I didn't say you could, I meant a manipulation of the value.  I'd much rather use a regex for the whole job than have to post-process the result of using the regex further - that approach, in my opinion, is far less readable, and if I came across code that did it, after spending time working out what they're doing I'd be left wondering "why didn't they just use the regex?"  There's also a good chance that actually you don't need the array, rather you'd then loop over it to process the values anyway, so any code you did there could have just been in the `exec` loop in the first place.

Comment: @JamesThorpe You should take an overview rather than just focusing on the `regex` part. I didn't say this regex is bad or worse. My whole complaint is about the loop. It's the one that makes this solution less readable.  And also, `"{{foo}} is {{bar}}".match(/{{.*?}}/g).map(s => s.slice(2, -2));` is not that *far less readable*.

Comment: @Tresdin: Real problem is use of `slice` which essentially is doing **additional string manipulation** to get the results. One will have to change this `slice` method as per the regex. But this `exec / loop` code remains same irrespective of whatever regex is used.

Comment: @anubhava You're talking about code efficiency, not readability. This solution is obviously more efficient. But what I want to say is, it's less readable.

Comment: @Tresdin a) readability is an opinion.  As I said further up, _"in my opinion"_ the opposite is true.  b) It's not just about efficiency, it's about technical debt, which is what my original point was (you brought up readability).  If the regex has to change at some point, you now have to change two things, as anubhava pointed out.

Comment: @Tresdin: Leaving aside efficiency, readability type issues. If input is `"{{foo}} is {bar} and {{{baz}}}"` and task is to **grab all any strings that are between 1 or more of `{` and `}`**. Can you tell me what would be `slice` method for that problem. Result should be `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` (btw above `exec / loop` will still work great with `re = /\{+(.*?)\}+/g`)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is fine, just use `map` to strip the braces

```js
    var output = "{{foo}} is {{bar}}".match(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g).map(function(value){ return value.substring(2,value.length-2)  });
    document.body.innerHTML += output;
```

Answer (score 1):

In JS, `match` with `g` only returns top-level matches, no groups. You can map the string as @gurvinder372 suggested:

```js
res = "{{foo}} is {{bar}}".match(/{{.*?}}/g).map(s => s.slice(2, -2));

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(res,0,3));
```

or use `.replace` to populate the array:

```js
res = [];

"{{foo}} is {{bar}}".replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, (_, $1) => res.push($1));


document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(res,0,3));
```

Note that there's no need to escape curly braces in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var arr = [];
var str = "{{foo}} is {{bar}}"
str.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function(s, match) {
                           arr.push(match);
                        });

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(arr));
```